# Best practice - Developing on a local mysql server / RDS?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, amazon-rds

I am developing a Drupal site using MariaDB.

The import process of a 77MB dump file locally (docker container running maria db) takes about 2 minutes.
The same import to an Amazon RDS (db.m4.large) running a MariaDB database takes more than 30 minutes.

Isn't the Amazon RDS supposed to be quicker ?

What is the recommended practice for having a quick dev environment for SQL ? (the local docker service is running too slow)

Thanks,
Yaron

Comment: Have you optimized mariadb for the type of hardware you are running? or just using defaults?

Comment: using defaults.

Comment: How far away (network-wise) is that cloud?

Comment: Additional information request from your Amazon RDS MariaDB instance. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server, number of cores/cpu's 
SSD IOPS from Amazon?
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Answer (score 2):

If you are already on RDS, just use a snapshot.

1. Take a snapshot from production. (or find one of the automated snapshots)
2. Create a new DB from the snapshot

It's very fast and doesn't have the issues of latency and running millions of queries which an import has.

However, this is just one very crude approach to making a dev environment.

Some people have scripts that create the data sat for DEV from scratch. This might be more appropriate and even necessary, if for example you have a large database and developers that like to work locally on their computer.

Some people have scripts that sanitize DEV to eliminate sensitive and personal data, which you could run after the snapshot.

Some people even have DEV as a replica of the main DB and modify the DEV db so that additional usage doesn't clash with the replicated changes. This is a bit delicate though.

Often Dev and Tests use dummy data, and Staging uses real data (cloned from Production and possibly sanitized).

Comment: But isn't RDS  db.m4.large supposed to be quicker than my local machine running docker ? it runs like 100 times slower.

Comment: When comparing the speed of import, you need to consider the  latency of running all of those queries. A lot of them.  How fast is your network?

Regardless creating from a rds snapshot doesn't involve running SQL statements.

Comment: A snapshot is great for speed but not always the best answer for development environments. It depends on data, a snapshot doesn't allow you to sanitize or de-personalize your production data, and depending on what you're working with and who works on it, that can be a big liability. Same is true for the backup-rds-restore-local process.

Comment: Good point @MatthewPoer I added that. Don't want people getting the wrong idea.

Comment: +1 updates make sense. I'll just add that from what I've seen, building dev data from scratch is the _most ideal_ situation (yet, so rarely done) for development and testing systems. `Dev|Test` uses dummy data, `Staging|Production` use real data where Staging is a recent snapshot/clone of Production :)

Comment: @GidonWise I understand that a snapshot is the better solution for a quicker import process - but regarding the use of the DB after it's been imported - do you recommend using a local one or an RDS ? Which gives better performance for development ?

Comment: A local DB will give better performance if you have too much latency. A remote one will give better performance if your data requires a lot of ram and cpu and IO. For a 77MB db, it's still small enough that probably in you case, a local db is probably a bit faster. But, do you really want people running around with laptops that have your whole dataset? There are security concerns as well. Also if there are so many queries that the latency is hurting you, I'd be concerned that your application is chatty. If there aren't I'd be concerned that you need a better internet connection. Good luck!